# Not able to set image in ImageView inside AlertDialog

Tags: android, android-glide

I have a aleart dialog with custom layout. I'm trying to set image for the imageview inside the AlertDialog.
I tried glide and and drawable. both doesnt seem to work. This is killing my time. What is wrong here?

**code**

```
   public void displayImage(String imgURL){


    AlertDialog.Builder alertViewPicture = new AlertDialog.Builder(SearchActivity.this);
    LayoutInflater factory = LayoutInflater.from(SearchActivity.this);
    final View view = factory.inflate(R.layout.dialog_image, null);
    // change the ImageView image source
    final ImageView dialogImageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageViewTest);
    dialogImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.bg_afternoon);

    alertViewPicture.setView(view);
    alertViewPicture.setTitle("Alert Dialog Title");
    alertViewPicture.setNeutralButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dlg, int sumthin) {

        }
    });

    alertViewPicture.show();

}
```

**xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageViewTest"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_road_blue"/>

 </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your have not written the wrong code because I have run your code it is working fine on my side please check screen shots

[image]

Please check your image in drawable, it may be issue with that or load the big image,so try to put the image in mipmap and use Glide if remote image url with current activity context/basecontext